# Rg.Plugins.Popup on device back button click in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

Once the Rg.Plugin.Popup is displayed, with

```
PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new PopupPage());
```

Once its displayed, and on pressing Device Back button. screen getting hanged.
No **OnBackPressed** in declared in the code.

Answer (score 0):

> Once its displayed, and on pressing Device Back button. screen getting hanged. No OnBackPressed in declared in the code.

From [this article](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/wiki/Getting-started#android-back-button), for Android back button to work with the plugin, you should invoke **Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.SendBackPressed** in your MainActivity in override method OnBackPressed.

```
 public async override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        if (Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.SendBackPressed(base.OnBackPressed))
        {
            // Do something if there are some pages in the `PopupStack`
            await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            // Do something if there are not any pages in the `PopupStack`
        }
    }
```